# why Iceberg rewriteDataFiles doesn't rewrite the files to one file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-iceberg

I have an iceberg table with 2 parquets files store 4 rows in s3
I tried the following command:

```
val tables = new HadoopTables(conf);
val table = tables.load("s3://iceberg-tests-storage/data/db/test5");    
SparkActions.get(spark).rewriteDataFiles(table).option("target-file-size-bytes", "52428800").execute();
```

but nothing changed.
what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few notes:

1. Iceberg by default won't compact files unless a minimum number of small files are available to compact per file group and per partition. The default is 5.

   - This can be [configured via `min-input-files`](https://github.com/apache/iceberg/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/iceberg/actions/BinPackStrategy.java#L59) as an option.
2. Iceberg won't compact files across partitions, as one file must map 1:1 to a tuple of partition values.

   - As an example: for a table partitioned by col1 and col2, files with col1=A and col2=1 cannot be compacted with files with col1=A and col2=4

In your case, if you set `min-input-files` to 2, provided the files are part of the same partition or the table is not partitioned, the files should be compacted together.